# Can Omni-Channel be used with Sales Cloud using Service Cloud feature license?

Tags: servicecloud, sales-cloud, omnichannel, lightning-console

Being on Sales Cloud only, can we make use of Omni-Channel for Lead Assignment using Service Cloud feature license?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can use omni-channel with lead using service cloud license. In my current project we have service cloud license and we are using omnichannel to route leads to agent.

Make sure on user record page, Service Cloud User checkbox is checked to receive lead in omni-channel. Any help on omni-channel feel free to contact me over here.

Comment: Thank you Manish for quick reply. My question we have project Sales Cloud only and with going for Service Cloud licenses, can we make use of Service Cloud Feature license?

Comment: Yes we can. Same scenario is in my current project. We have service cloud licenses but we are using omni-channel skill based routing for lead in sales cloud.

Comment: You mean Sales Cloud?

Comment: Yes, sales cloud. But to recieve lead in Omnichannel on user there is a service cloud use check box field that should be checked.